# How to change tool bar and text background color using palette API picking from image dynamically

Tags: android, android-palette

hi i am new to android i want to change my toolbar and text background color dynamically picking color using palette color picker from image ,any one please help me how to change my toolbar color i have multi images   from json object how to change toolbar and text background from JSON,i want to change my toolbar color on every item when i click,plaese any one please help me how to got this 
HERE BELOW MY CODE

Meanswear.java

```
int pos = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_means_wear);

    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    tv5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    tex1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    pos = Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras()).getString("pos"));

    tv1.setText(Women_clothing.gridData.get(pos).getDocumentName());

    tv3.setText(Women_clothing.gridData.get(pos).getDocumentContent());
    tv4.setText(Women_clothing.gridData.get(pos).getOffer());
    tv5.setText(Women_clothing.gridData.get(pos).getAddress());

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load((Women_clothing.gridData.get(pos)).getDocumentFile()).into(image);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following

```
public static void colorizeToolbar(Toolbar toolbarView, int toolbarIconsColor, Activity activity) {
    final PorterDuffColorFilter colorFilter
            = new PorterDuffColorFilter(toolbarIconsColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

    for(int i = 0; i < toolbarView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View v = toolbarView.getChildAt(i);

        //Step 1 : Changing the color of back button (or open drawer button).
        if(v instanceof ImageButton) {
            //Action Bar back button
            ((ImageButton)v).getDrawable().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
        }

        if(v instanceof ActionMenuView) {
            for(int j = 0; j < ((ActionMenuView)v).getChildCount(); j++) {

                //Step 2: Changing the color of any ActionMenuViews - icons that
                //are not back button, nor text, nor overflow menu icon.
                final View innerView = ((ActionMenuView)v).getChildAt(j);

                if(innerView instanceof ActionMenuItemView) {
                    int drawablesCount = ((ActionMenuItemView)innerView).getCompoundDrawables().length;
                    for(int k = 0; k < drawablesCount; k++) {
                        if(((ActionMenuItemView)innerView).getCompoundDrawables()[k] != null) {
                            final int finalK = k;

                            //Important to set the color filter in seperate thread, 
                            //by adding it to the message queue
                            //Won't work otherwise.
                            innerView.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    ((ActionMenuItemView) innerView).getCompoundDrawables()[finalK].setColorFilter(colorFilter);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Step 3: Changing the color of title and subtitle.
        toolbarView.setTitleTextColor(toolbarIconsColor);
        toolbarView.setSubtitleTextColor(toolbarIconsColor);

        //Step 4: Changing the color of the Overflow Menu icon.
        setOverflowButtonColor(activity, colorFilter);
    }
}
```

See this [Example 1](https://snow.dog/blog/how-to-dynamicaly-change-android-toolbar-icons-color/)  [Example 2](http://blog.brightinventions.pl/playing-with-material-design-toolbar-palette/)

Comment: its working but my navigation bar color was not changing how to change that @Aditya

Comment: for that just use this .setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)